# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at line 1 column 40 path $.result.loggedUser

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit2

I'm trying to consume an API in kotlin and this is the first time I'm working with API's and especially with retrofit, I checked online for a solution but I couldn't understand how to go about with this.
this is the API link

```
https://connect.managedcoder.com/api/leaves
```

inorder to get the response I have to pass a token as part of the parameter so the link has to be :

```
https://connect.managedcoder.com/api/leaves?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InNoYW5lLnBlcmVpcmFAc2ppbm5vdmF0aW9uLmNvbSIsInBhc3N3b3JkIjoicGFzc3dvcmQxMjMifQ.ncwng1CK8Y2N4z7ZofgB94ZVxJ8V5L8fk1JKGLnNr2s
```

however, the API fails and it returns the above error and goes into the on failure method.
I'm not sure if the way I have constructed the URL while calling the API is correct and if that is the cause of the issue, or it is due to some other reason.

This is my response to the API :

```
{
"status": "OK",
"result": {
    "loggedUser": {
        "id": 119,
        "first_name": "Shane",
        "last_name": "Pereira",
        "emp_id": "Goa6",
        "personal_email": "shanepereira30@gmail.com",
        "office_email": "shane.pereira@sjinnovation.com",
        "present_address": "Hno. 172 Church Street Cortalim Goa 403710",
        "permanent_address": "Hno. 172 Church Street Cortalim Goa 403710",
        "mobile_number": "2147483647",
        "alternate_number": "2147483647",
        "emergency_number": "2147483647",
        "country": "India",
        "office_location": "GOA",
        "gender": 1,
        "birth_date": "1970-01-01T00:00:00",
        "maritial_status": null,
        "identity_proof": "",
        "blood_group": "",
        "bank_name": "",
        "bank_account_number": "",
        "salary": null,
        "tax_bracket": "",
        "languages": "",
        "max_qualification": "--",
        "designation_id": 33,
        "shift_type": "09:00 - 18:00",
        "department_id": null,
        "reporting_team": "",
        "reporting_manager": "",
        "reporting_manager_responsibilities": "0",
        "mentor": "",
        "date_of_joining": "2019-01-03T00:00:00",
        "source_of_hire": "",
        "referred_by": "",
        "employment_status": "1",
        "work_phone": "8390429861",
        "employment_type": "full-time",
        "confirmation_date": "2019-06-03T00:00:00",
        "increment_date": "1970-01-01T00:00:00",
        "resignation_date": "1970-01-01T00:00:00",
        "last_working_date": "1970-01-01T00:00:00",
        "notice_period": "2 Months ",
        "reason": "",
        "blacklisted": "",
        "notes": "",
        "knowledge": "--",
        "role_id": 4,
        "is_manager": 0,
        "created": "2019-03-18T11:40:48",
        "modified": "2019-03-18T11:40:48",
        "profile_pic": "",
        "is_pm": 0,
        "hubstaff_name": null
    },
    "error": "No Leave days has been assigned. Please contact with HR.",
    "success": false
}
```

}

this is my get request

```
  @GET("api/leaves?")
fun getLeaveData(
   @Query("token")token:String
):Call<LoginResponse>
```

this is my retrofit instance :

```
object RetrofitClient {
private val  AUTH = "Basic"
private const val  BASE_URL = "https://connect.managedcoder.com/"
private val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor{chain ->
            val original = chain.request()
            val RequestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Authorization", "")
                .method(original.method(),original.body())
            val request = RequestBuilder.build()
            chain.proceed(request)
        }.build()
val instance: Api by lazy {
    val retrofit= Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build()

    retrofit.create(Api::class.java)
}
```

}

and I have 3 classes which are LoginResponse, Result, and User
the LoginResponse contains the result and status of the response, the result contains the token, success and holds the logged user details from the user class  which contains the id, name, and email

Login response:

```
data class LoginResponse ( val status: String, val result:Result) {
```

}

Result:

```
data class Result (val token:String, val success: String,val loggedUser: User){

}
```

User:

```
data class User(val id:Int?, val office_email: String?, val first_name: String?)
```

and here is where I call the API

```
    if(token!=""){
    RetrofitClient.instance.getLeaveData(token)
        .enqueue(object :retrofit2.Callback<LoginResponse> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<LoginResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"error"+t.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                Log.d("xxerror response xxxxx", t.message)
            }

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<LoginResponse>,
                response: Response<LoginResponse>
            ) {
                // Toast.makeText(context,response.body()?.result?.success, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                if (response.body()?.status=="OK"){
                    Toast.makeText(context,"mellooooo"+response.body()?.result?.loggedUser?.first_name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(context,"api failed to load"+response.body()?.status,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }

            }

        })
}else{
    Toast.makeText(context,"token is empty",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    val i=  Intent(activity, LoginActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(i)
    SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this.requireContext()).clear()
}
```

Comment: @GET("api/leaves?") -> Changed   @GET("api/leaves")

Comment: well, I did try that too, still doesn't work.

Comment: data class Result (val token:String, val success: String,val loggedUser: User){

}


In the json model, "error" appears instead of the "token."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the GET request provided above, below is the response.

```
{"status":"OK","result":{"loggedUser":0,"error":"No Leave days has been assigned. Please contact with HR.","success":false}}
```

You can see that `loggedUser` is `0` instead of `null`

When the `success=false` the User Model expected is `JsonObject` and but response is an `Int` thus an error. Reason why it does not fall into onError block because it's not an HTTP error but a business logic error.

You can manually serialise the object based on `success` using Gson or ask the server to send `null` instead of `0`